# WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!

Tags: debian, cron, email

**Problem:**

I get an email with the following message each day:

> Final-Recipient: rfc822; root@mywebsite.com Action: failed Status:
>   5.0.0 Diagnostic-Code: smtp; The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email
>   address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser m80sor786079wmg.52 -
>   gsmtp Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 23:32:30 -0700 (PDT)
>
> ---------- Doorgestuurd bericht ---------- From: Cron Daemon  To: root@mywebsite.com Cc:  Bcc:  Date:
>   Thu, 19 Apr 2018 06:32:28 +0000 (UTC) Subject: Cron 
>   test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report
>   /etc/cron.daily ) /etc/cron.daily/apt: WARNING: The following packages
>   cannot be authenticated!   google-compute-engine
>   google-compute-engine-jessie google-config-jessie
>   google-compute-engine-init-jessie

**Possible solution:**

If I am right, it is about packages that should be updated, making the system trying to send an email to root@mywebsite.com, but this email does not exist.

Do you think I can solve the problem by updating the packages?

Comment: You have 2 different problems : 1) The google packages can't be authenticated 2) the cron mail address does not exist, therefore the error report of 1) can't be sent

Comment: Ok. But I can not find how to change the cron mail address..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a key, run this to get a new key

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

after that upgrade your packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```